# Use modified decompiled files in later builds in C#

Tags: c#, rider

When I am inspecting code, I often find my self reading and modifying decompiled files. Rider or Resharper decompile files automatically.

Later on, I add a bunch of `Console.WriteLine()`, to better understand what the program is doing. The problem is, changes made to decompiled code are not shown in subsequent runs/ builds of the program. Therefore I cannot inspect the code, because the original never changed.

What should I do, so that the decompiled files are used instead of the original ones in the newly executed runs? Is there some checkbox that needs to be checked?

Comment: Why would you edit the temporary decompiled file instead of editing the actual source? Those files are exactly that **temporary**, if they we're meant to be reused in subsequent runs they wouldn't be temporary

Comment: For learning purposes. Imagine an already compiled project that is part of the larger project you want to learn from. Making changes and seeing what they do gives you insight.

Comment: Why don't you operate on the original projects sources?

Comment: The class that I would like to modify is part of a .dll file. If I find the dll file and then open the class I am interested in, it still opens as a decompiled file.

Comment: If you want changes to decompiled code to be effective then you'll have to create a project for it.  So you'll build a new DLL, which you can now reference in a program.  Also be safe and change the [AssemblyVersion] so you won't get one from the GAC.  Do favor using the debugger instead of Console.WriteLine() calls so none of this is necessary.